# Unknown encoder 'libx264'

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, x264, avconv

I installed ffmpeg 0.8.9 on ubuntu11 by

> ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-pthreads
>   --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264

When I run it

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mp4 -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64k -vcodec libx264 -b 250k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 5 -trellis 1 -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 250k -maxrate 250k -bufsize 250k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 320:240 -g 30 -async 2 a.ts
```

It said

> Unknown encoder 'libx264'

(Note: the same error could occour with `avconv`)

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Is x264 installed on the system (should be as easy as "apt-get install libx264-dev" on Ubuntu)? Does "ffmpeg -codecs" have a libx264 line?

Comment: What is the precise underlying problem, though? I have files in /opt/lib "libx264.so" "libx264.so." "libx264.a". The exact problem must be that these files need to be found and are not (eg opt/lib isn't in LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 11.04, and I also came across this error - `Unknown encoder 'libx264'`. Installing the package `libavcodec-extra-53` resolved the problem.

In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the package that is needed is called `libavcodec-extra-54` (and `libav-tools`)

Comment: Maybe I have not been keeping up with updates, but on my Ubuntu 11.04 I had to install libavcodec-extra-52, 53 didn't exist.

Comment: This one worked for me, to get simplescreenrecorder encoding in x264.

Comment: Still necessary (and working) in Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy).

Comment: Why does installing this package remove a huge number of installed encoders? Is this part of that irritating dispute between whoever writes ffmpeg and whoever write avconv?

Comment: Meanwhile it's `libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56` (and simply `libavcodec-extra`)

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04: `sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra57 libavformat57 libavutil55`. https://askubuntu.com/a/852608/775359

Comment: Check also which ffmpeg you are using, especially if you are working with anaconda. You should use /usr/bin/ffmpeg

Answer (score 45):

start by installing these libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libfdk-aac-dev libass-dev libopus-dev  \
libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libvpx-dev libssl-dev
```

For Ubuntu 20.04 issue

```
sudo apt-get install nasm
```

and hop over this manual nasm install ... yet as of Ubuntu 17.04   `sudo apt-get install nasm`  does not supply a new enough nasm so install that manually

get source for nasm at
http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/?C=M;O=D
download the latest then

```
cd ~/src/nasm-2.13.02  #  update to release you just downloaded
./configure
make -j $(nproc)
sudo make install
```

Then for x264 :

```
git clone https://code.videolan.org/videolan/x264.git
cd x264
./configure --enable-static --enable-shared
make -j $(nproc)
sudo make install
```

For mp3 get LAME (libmp3lame)

```
sudo apt-get install libmp3lame-dev
```

or install manually from http://lame.sourceforge.net/ version v3.100, then give it the normal

```
cd lame-3.100/
./configure
make -j $(nproc)
sudo make install
```

Finally download ffmpeg source and do install :

```
git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git
cd ffmpeg

./configure  --enable-gpl   --enable-libass   --enable-libfdk-aac   --enable-libfreetype   --enable-libmp3lame   --enable-libopus   --enable-libtheora   --enable-libvorbis   --enable-libvpx   --enable-libx264   --enable-nonfree --enable-shared --enable-openssl   

make -j $(nproc)
sudo make install
```

I feel your pain, but this works - still valid on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: I tried this, but the `configure` in the last step gives the following error: "libfaac not found"

Comment: +1 - This worked for me on Mac OS Mavericks (10.9.4).  I was fighting to try and install `libx264` so it can be integrated into `FFMPEG` for about 2 hours.  Thank you so much!

Comment: `--enable-libfaac` does not work for me. Not sure if it is the same, but I used this param `--enable-libfdk-aac`, previously installing `apt install libfdk-aac-dev`

Comment: @jperelli cool now updated ... above is current for Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: error in the x264 part step make -j8:
filters/video/resize.c: In function ‘pick_closest_supported_csp’:
filters/video/resize.c:215:30: error: ‘AVComponentDescriptor {aka const struct AVComponentDescriptor}’ has no member named ‘depth’
         if( pix_desc->comp[i].depth > 8 )
                              ^
Makefile:277: recipe for target 'filters/video/resize.o' failed
make: *** [filters/video/resize.o] Error 1

Comment: This solution worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04, but after the last step I needed to also do `sudo apt-get upgrade ffmpeg`

Answer (score 18):

I got this error with Ubuntu 18 while using OpenAI Gym. You need correct versions of ffmpeg and x264 encoder. To get them, I used following and it worked:

```
conda install x264=='1!152.20180717' ffmpeg=4.0.2 -c conda-forge
```

Comment: this one worked for me. I did try to install ffmpeg from `snap` and snap does enable `libx264` but once I installed `ffmpeg-python`, the `conda` automatically installed `ffmpeg` again, the auto-installed ffmpeg has the libx264 disabled. So installing ffmpeg with conda for this specific version is the one and ONLY working solution for me.