# ffmpeg x264 codec increses the Video Bitrate

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have Installed ffmpeg and x264 based on this post :

[Unknown encoder 'libx264'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764740/unknown-encoder-libx264)

no errors receved. but when i want to convert an input stream from mumudvb to a lower bitrate with x264 codec the ffmpeg output will increase the bitrate to about 26000 ! im trying to get 512k Bitrate,
the wierd thing is that my input's bitrate is 3000k but when i get the ffmpeg's output in vlc it shows inputs bitrate as 30000

this is my config :

```
Port 8888
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 20000
MaxClients 10000
MaxBandwidth 1000000
CustomLog -
<Feed ch1.ffm>
File /tmp/ch1.ffm
FileMaxSize 100M
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
launch ffmpeg -i http://127.0.0.1:8081
</Feed>

<Stream ch1>
Feed ch1.ffm
Format mpegts
AudioBitRate 64
AudioChannels 2
AudioSampleRate 44100
#AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
VideoBitRate 512
VideoBufferSize 400
VideoFrameRate 25
VideoBitRateTolerance 100
VideoSize 720x576
VideoGopSize 12
AudioCodec aac
VideoCodec libx264
AVOptionVideo bsf h264_mp4toannexb
#AVOptionVideo threads 0
AVOptionVideo threads_type frame
AVOptionVideo coder 0
AVOptionVideo bf 0
AVOptionVideo flags +loop
AVOptionVideo partitions +parti8x8+parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8
AVOptionVideo me_method hex
AVOptionVideo subq 7
AVOptionVideo me_range 16
AVOptionVideo g 250
AVOptionVideo keyint_min 10
AVOptionVideo sc_threshold 40
AVOptionVideo i_qfactor 0.71
AVOptionVideo b_strategy 1
AVOptionVideo qcomp 0.6
AVOptionVideo qmin 10
AVOptionVideo qmax 51
AVOptionVideo qdiff 4
AVOptionVideo refs 3
AVOptionVideo directpred 1
AVOptionVideo trellis 1
AVOptionVideo wpredp 0
#AVOptionVideo flags +global_header

StartSendOnKey
</Stream>
```

Comment: does any one has an idea ?

Comment: maybe want to add a "K" on that VideoBitRate ?

Comment: i did its not that ..

Comment: You are saying vlc showed your input bitrate as 30000 and the output bitrate is around 26000 which is actually a reduction.