# Writing video with x264 Fourcc in Videowriter class in opencv

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, h.264

I wanted to do a very simple project of giving a program an input video which is saved in the same directory as "my_video" without any processing steps. I specifically want to use the H.264 compression format. Hence I chose 'X','2','6','4' Fourcc and the program popped out the following errors.

broken ffmpeg default settings detected
use an encoding preset (e.g. -vpre medium)
preset usage: -vpre  -vpre 
speed presets are listed in x264 --help
profile is optional; x264 defaults to high
Could not open codec 'libx264': Unspecified error

So how do I install libx264 and configure it to work with opencv.I tried setting the fourcc value to -1 to do it by hand but no Window popped up requesting me to choose one of the available codec.( isn't that supposed to happen).

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have this same problem. All the answers I've found say to download ffmpeg and that's the end of the instructions. In the ffmpeg downloads I don't see any DLLs that opencv is looking for. Unless this is yet another example of opencv silently failing when it can't find a DLL.

Comment: The window only pops up if you're using Windows.  If you're using Mac or Linux, you're SOL.  BTW, your previous question on how to get the VideoWriter working I answered... and I told you in the comments that you need to configure X264 yourself.  This answer by Scott Stensland worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15105901/325082