# Compiled ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

am on shared hosting that doesn't support the use of ffmpeg. I've been busy since last week doing research on google on how to load my videos with my own static build of ffmpeg binary, from there I learn the one can use compiled ffmpeg. Have search for this file but to no avail. Pls where can I get this file or which search key can I use to search it on google. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to learn details on how to use a compiler it's a good thing to go to StackOverflow, but in your case, I'd say someone on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) can give you a good advice. Anyways, it would be nice to know what shared hosting you are on or what operating system you are using. With that information there might even be something on the [ffmpeg compilation guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide)

Comment: Yeah... Compiling my own ffmpeg is the best like you said, I should have done that but my computer is having problem. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Download **FFmpeg** binaries from [zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com) if using Windows!

Comment: see steps on how to compile and install ffmpeg on Ubuntu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764740/unknown-encoder-libx264/15105901#15105901