# Excuting ffmpeg commands using Python to locate *.png failed

Tags: python, bash, ffmpeg

The following command works well if I run it in the Bash terminal.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i 'data/*.png' -i data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_cut.wav -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_out.mp4
```

However, If i run it using `os.system()` using Python.

```
os.system(r"ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i '/data/share/VFHQ/data/extracted_cropped_face_results/_-91nXXjrVo/Clip+_-91nXXjrVo+P0+C0+F1537-1825/*.png' -i /data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_cut.wav -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p /data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/out.mp4")
```

I get `Unknown encoder 'libx264'`

If I remove the quotation mark inside the commands

```
os.system(r"ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i /data/share/VFHQ/data/extracted_cropped_face_results/_-91nXXjrVo/Clip+_-91nXXjrVo+P0+C0+F1537-1825/*.png -i /data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_cut.wav -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p /data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/out.mp4")
```

I get `Option pattern_type not found.`

So I tried `subprocess.run(command,shell=True)` , I get same results as shown above.

Running 'subprocess.run()' without Shell will result in the following"

```
subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-framerate', '25','-pattern_type', 'glob', '-i','/data/share/VFHQ/data/extracted_cropped_face_results/_-91nXXjrVo/Clip+_-91nXXjrVo+P0+C0+F1537-1825/*.png',
                '-i','/data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_cut.wav','-c:v','libx264','-pix_fmt','yuv420p','/data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_out.mp4'])
```

```
[image2 @ 0x56001a8fee00] Could find no file with path '/data/share/VFHQ/data/extracted_cropped_face_results/_-91nXXjrVo/Clip+_-91nXXjrVo+P0+C0+F1537-1825/*.png' and index in the range 0-4
/data/share/VFHQ/data/extracted_cropped_face_results/_-91nXXjrVo/Clip+_-91nXXjrVo+P0+C0+F1537-1825/*.png: No such file or directory
```

---

With out the quotation marks on the picture directory:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['ffmpeg', '-framerate', '25', '-pattern_type', 'glob', '-i', '/data/share/VFHQ/data/extracted_cropped_face_results/_-91nXXjrVo/Clip+_-91nXXjrVo+P0+C0+F1537-1825/*.png', '-i', '/data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_cut.wav', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '/data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_out.mp4'], returncode=1)
```

`Unknown encoder 'libx264'`

with quotation marks around the picture directory (also the correct way to run in the terminal):

```
subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-framerate', '25','-pattern_type', 'glob', '-i',"'/data/share/VFHQ/data/extracted_cropped_face_results/_-91nXXjrVo/Clip+_-91nXXjrVo+P0+C0+F1537-1825/*.png'",
                '-i','/data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_cut.wav','-c:v','libx264','-pix_fmt','yuv420p','/data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_out.mp4'])
```

`'/data/share/VFHQ/data/extracted_cropped_face_results/_-91nXXjrVo/Clip+_-91nXXjrVo+P0+C0+F1537-1825/*.png': No such file or directory`

---

It was later found out that I have 2versions of ffmpeg. One is 4.3 the other is 4.4.2
The thing is running a subprocess with quotation marks (I know it is incorrect as it has been explained) will call v4.4.2. Running it without quotation marks will call the v4.3 ffmpeg.

Also from V4.3 log, it suggests  `Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'libx264'.` but in the end

```
[wav @ 0x55eaef48b240] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 204878 bytes read:294990 seeks:1 frames:50
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, wav, from '/data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_cut.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.44, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #1:0, 50, 1/48000: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url /data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_out.mp4.
Applying option c:v (codec name) with argument libx264.
Applying option pix_fmt (set pixel format) with argument yuv420p.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: /data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_out.mp4.
Unknown encoder 'libx264'
[AVIOContext @ 0x55eaef487fc0] Statistics: 294990 bytes read, 1 seeks
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253709/discussion-on-question-by-leo-excuting-ffmpeg-commands-using-python-to-locate); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to add another level of quotes around the pathname, since it's not being processed by the shell.

```
subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-framerate', '25','-pattern_type', 'glob', 
                '-i','/data/share/VFHQ/data/extracted_cropped_face_results/_-91nXXjrVo/Clip+_-91nXXjrVo+P0+C0+F1537-1825/*.png',
                '-i','/data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_cut.wav','-c:v','libx264','-pix_fmt','yuv420p',
                '/data/share/VFHQ/data/download_youtube/_-91nXXjrVo_out.mp4'])
```

Comment: We've told the OP this (repeatedly!), and they've asserted that the problem doesn't go away when they fix it.

Comment: As I copied pasted, this code leads to `Unknown encoder 'libx264'`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764740/unknown-encoder-libx264

Comment: @Barmar I follow the link and installed the newest `libavcodec-extra59` but it did not solve the problem

Comment: It's not a python problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's contribution.

To locate the problem, we place `-report` in the `ffmpeg` argument for a detailed log. Doing this allows me to find out that there are 2 versions of `ffmpeg` in my system.

To solve the problem, run `whereis ffmpeg` to locate the 2 versions of `ffmpeg` then add the absolute directory of the `ffmpeg` when running it. For instance  `/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i xxxxxx`

There is a phenomenon where the version of `ffmpeg` called in Python is not fixed. In other words, the `v3.2` is called if I do not quote the directory in the command (which is also not needed for `subprocess` or `os.system()`) and 'v4.4.2` will be called if I place quotation marks. This problem is unknown.